# Do Not Expand Flex Grow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created a codepen to illustrate my problem: https://codepen.io/chasenbettinger/pen/JBozOL

If the row cannot hold the box and thus it moves it to a new row, I am trying to get the size of that box to be the same size as the items on the top row. In other words, I want the responsiveness of flex-grow, but I do not want the div to expand the entire space of the div if it is on a new line. If I didn't use the `max-width` property, the two boxes on the bottom would expand the entire size of the div.

Am I approaching this problem the wrong way?

Comment: I would say not possible without media query or a lot of hack ... there is a duplicate for this with some workarounds but not able to find it

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ya.. that's what I was thinking. That's why I asked if I was approaching the problem correctly. Maybe this is a better use for grid?

Comment: well with grid you will be obliged to define a width value and you can also do this with flex

Comment: @TemaniAfif if you don't mind me asking; how would you solve this problem? Is it best to the let items grow within their container?

Comment: well, I cannot tell you if it's the best or not, but to solve this I would first try media query and maybe use some hack with pseudo element to reduce the effect :  https://jsfiddle.net/pquoLt07/ .. then you play with other value to have what you need